# drawing a transition state integrated in a matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, matrices, tikz-graphdrawing

I already know how to draw a transition state using `TikZ` but I need to draw something a little bit more complicated. Here is a picture of the diagram that I want to draw:

[image]

Can somebody help me please to draw this is latex?

Comment: As always, you'll have more chance to get help here if you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) showing what you tried already and asking for a specific question instead of something like *do it for me*.

Answer (score 2):

I happened to have an example of how to color specific pairs of coordinates with `NiceTabular` using `\CodeAfter`.

The loop in `\foreach` uses `evaluate=\x as \i using {int(\x+2)}` in order to correct the coordinate's shift due to extras row and columns of your table, so you can just type the coordinates as your are looking to your dots in a matrix.

First table uses my original sketch with colors and the second one reproduces your suggested design.

The MWE follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{p{2cm} ccc}
  \diagbox{{\tiny road}}{{\tiny time}} & $t = 1$ & $t = 2$ & $t = 3$ \\
  segment                              & $z_1$   & $z_2$   & $z_3$   \\
  $r_1$                                & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  $r_2$                                & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  $r_3$                                & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  $r_4$                                & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  \vdots                               & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  \\
  $r_{N_r}$                            & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  \CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3mm, opacity=0.5, line cap=round]
    \foreach \x/\y/\c/\p/\q [
    evaluate=\x as \i using {int(\x+2)}, evaluate=\y as \j using {int(\y+1)},
    evaluate=\p as \u using {int(\p+2)}, evaluate=\q as \v using {int(\q+1)}] in
    {1/1/blue/1/2, 1/1/blue/2/2, 2/1/red/1/2, 2/1/red/2/2, 3/1/green/1/2, 3/1/green/2/2,
      1/2/yellow/1/3, 1/2/yellow/2/3, 2/2/orange/1/3,  2/2/orange/2/3}{
      \draw [\c] (\i-\j.center) node[black]{$\bullet$} -- (\u-\v.center) node[black]{$\bullet$};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}


\begin{NiceTabular}{p{2cm} ccc}
  \diagbox{{\tiny road}}{{\tiny time}} & $t = 1$ & $t = 2$ & $t = 3$ \\
  segment                              & $z_1$   & $z_2$   & $z_3$   \\
  $r_1$                                & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  $r_2$                                & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  $r_3$                                & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  $r_4$                                & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  \vdots                               & \vdots  & \vdots  & \vdots  \\
  $r_{N_r}$                            & $\circ$ & $\circ$ & $\circ$ \\
  \CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture}[very thick]
    \foreach \x/\y/\p/\q [
    evaluate=\x as \i using {int(\x+2)}, evaluate=\y as \j using {int(\y+1)},
    evaluate=\p as \u using {int(\p+2)}, evaluate=\q as \v using {int(\q+1)}] in
    {1/1/1/2, 1/1/2/2, 2/1/1/2, 2/1/2/2, 3/1/1/2, 3/1/2/2,
      1/2/1/3, 1/2/2/3, 2/2/1/3,  2/2/2/3}{
      \draw (\i-\j.center) node{$\bullet$} -- (\u-\v.center) node{$\bullet$};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

Results are:

[image].